# Is there a Ruby Hash#to_s equivalent for the 'new' Hash syntax?

Tags: ruby, serialization, hashmap

[Hash#to_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-to_s) (alias for inspect) always outputs data in the 1.8 hash style:

```
{key: "value"}.to_s
=> "{:key=>\"value\"}"
```

Is there any core method that will serialize it in the 1.9 hash style?

```
{key: "value"}.to_s
=> "{key: \"value\"}"
```

I'm using this on known data for code refactoring; and since Ruby tends to have an implementation of everything, I'm hoping I was just looking in the wrong place.

Of course, you could hack it in an ugly fashion

```
"{" + my_hash.to_a.map{|pair| pair[0].to_s + ": " + pair[1].inspect} * ",\n") + "}"
```

But I'm hoping there's a core method somewhere that's unit tested and fully correct.

Comment: The 1.9 "style" is syntactic sugar that is only valid when the keys are `Symbol`s (and not all Symbols are supported, but a subset with specific characters), I'm not sure if any core method will generate it, due to that limitation.

Comment: Correct; I would expect an exception in that instance.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me ... and it respects string keys.

```
{key: "value"}.to_s.gsub(/(:(\w+)\s?=>\s?)/, "\\2: ")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'json'
{key: "value"}.to_json

=> "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
```

Comment: Close, but not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for `{key: "value"}`, not `{"key":"value"}`